# Will 10666 RAM work in a machine that came with 10600?

Tags: memory, compatibility

I suspect the answer is that I won't have a problem, but I would just like to check.

My laptop came with PC3-1333 10600S RAM and I just purchased PC3-1333 10666 RAM. Will the 10666 RAM cause any problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problems, they're both the same DDR3-1333 standard. The peak transfer rate of DDR3-1333 modules is 10666 MB/s and some manufacturers report it with full precision while others choose to round it down to 10600 or up to 10700.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia's article on DDR3 SDRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules)
- [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/274587-31-10600-10666-what-difference#t2045244)